# Difference between Cox Proportional Harzards Model and interval-based logistic model for survival regressions

Tags: survival, cox-model, discrete-time

I have a dataset of timestamped trader transactions (to the second). I want to conduct a survival analysis on the trades where a trade is started at `startTime` and ends at `endTime` when the trader closes his position (i.e. the event). In my sample, all trades are closed, however these trades are opened at different times. A sample of my data looks like this:

```
ID    Buy(1)/Sell(0)  StartTime              EndTime                PnL Event   gainLoss
1           1         2013-01-03 04:05:14    2013-01-03 04:05:56    7    1      1
1           1         2013-01-05 07:07:36    2013-01-05 08:04:33    5    1      1
1           0         2013-01-06 08:12:12    2013-01-07 08:16:16    6    1      1
2           1         2013-01-06 08:12:18    2013-01-06 09:10:13    8    1      1
2           0         2013-01-08 09:24:25    2013-01-10 06:24:14   -9    1      0
2           0         2013-01-09 09:31:24    2013-01-10 06:23:10    3    1      1
```

`gainLoss` is a dummy variable equal to 1 if `PnL` is positive, and 0 if `PnL` is negative. `Event` is equal to 1 for all trades since they are all closed.

I have over 2 million trades and over 50,000 traders. I want to run a survival regression by accounting for trader `ID` as a random effect, so i am using the `coxme` package in R as follows:

`coxme.model <- coxme(Surv(startSec1, startSec2, Event) ~ gainLoss + (1|ID), data)`

where `startSec1` is the time in seconds between the beginning of the study (2013-01-01 00:00:00) and the `StartTime` of the trade, and `startSec2` is the time in seconds between the beginning of the study (2013-01-01 00:00:00) and the `EndTime` of the trade. The difference between `startSec2` and `startSec1` is the duration of the trade.

However this is taking a lot of time, presumably due to the large number of `IDs`. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Also, there is a similar study which runs a panel logistic model with data recorded at 10-minute intervals, such as:

`glmer.model <- glmer(Event~gainLoss + (1|ID), data)`

where `Event` is 0 throughout the duration of a trade except at the time of closing (it would turn to 1) .

My main question is which of the above two models is more appropriate to use? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

My concern regarding the logistic model is that, if a trade starts and ends in under 10 minutes (i.e. the event occurs at 5 minutes after start), does recording the Event at 10-minute intervals bias the results?

What are the consequences of using a discrete time model on data that is in continuous time?

Comment: Your interest seems to be in the relation of trade duration (`endTime` - `startTime`) to a measure of trade gain, while taking variability among traders into account. Is there some reason why you can't simply use the trade duration as your outcome variable? The Cox approach, so useful if events are censored, would seem to add unnecessary baggage in this case where there is no censoring. Also, you seem to have (semi)-quantitative data on absolute gain/loss in your `PnL` variable. Why are you throwing that information away by breaking it down into the dichotomized `gainLoss` variable?

Comment: That is correct, the relation I am interested in is trade duration. I am using a Cox model to account for the fact that not all trades are started at the same time (i.e. left truncation). Although I could probably do it as a logit model, I would then have to use discrete time units (which is my question, what would be the consequences for using discrete time? loss of info?). I use gain/loss because the theory I am testing is whether traders close their positions early if it is a gain (regardless of the amount of gain), but you are right it results in loss of info.